# TeXstudio syntax highlighting marked superscript and subscript as "outside math env" even when in math mode

Tags: color, texstudio, bm

This is just a visual annoyance as my code still works but it would be nice to know how to get rid of the pink highlights.

[image]

Comment: Please give us enough code (as text, not an image) so that we can see that you're in math mode.  This appears to be a property of your code editor, so you'll need to tell us that as well.

Comment: $$\bm{= \textcolor{Dandelion}{\theta_1 a^2} \;-\; \textcolor{YellowGreen}{\theta_2 b^2}} \;+\; \textbf{2(Area of} \; \bm{\triangle}\textbf{ABC)}$$  I'm using TeXStudio.

Comment: Please make this a complete example.  I don't know how you've defined `\bm`.  And please edit it into your question.  (And do you need `\bm` and `\textcolor` to get the improper highlighting, or can you eliminate one of them to make your example even simpler?)

Comment: I just used the bm package to bold things in math mode.  The highlights only seem to show up when I use it though, so good question.

Comment: @Nate To avoid the pink highlighting from TeXstudio, you could use `{\color{Dandelion}\theta_1 a^2}` instead of `\textcolor{Dandelion}{\theta_1 a^2}`

Comment: `\textcolor` most likely exits math mode.  But really, please edit a compilable example into your question, an example that begins with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and demonstrates the problem as described.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it doesn't exit math, but a syntax highlighter might think it does

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to TeXstudio, but the following may work for you. Observe that the code uses `\mathcolor`, not `\textcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\[
= \mathcolor{Dandelion}{\bm{\theta_1 a^2}} 
- \mathcolor{YellowGreen}{\bm{\theta_2 b^2}} 
+ \textbf{2(Area of $\bm{\triangle}\mathbf{ABC}$)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll need a new-ish -- vintage mid-2022 or newer -- TeX distribution to use `\mathcolor`. You'll probably also need an up to date version of TeXstudio, i.e., a version that's been trained to "recognize" the `\mathcolor` macro.